# Code to convert the bmp-image to binary image using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

There is no error in the following code which convert the gray image to binary image but it doesn't work... I need help to determine why the code doesn't work...I,m using vb,net 2012

```
    Dim mp3 As Double
    mp2 = 0
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim img As New Bitmap(600, 600)
    ' PictureBox2.Cls()
    For i = 0 To w
        For j = 0 To h
            ab(i, j) = 0
            zxc(i, j) = 0
            zxc1(i, j) = 0
            ssc(i, j) = 0
        Next j

    Next i
    For i = 0 To w - 17 Step 16
        For j = 0 To h - 17 Step 16
            mp1 = 0
            For k = i To i + 15
                For l = j To j + 15
                    mp1 = mp1 + imageArray(k, l)
            Next l, k
            mp1 = mp1 / (16 ^ 2)
            For k = i To i + 15
                For l = j To j + 15
                    If imageArray(k, l) >= mp1 Then
                        ssc(k, l) = 255
                    Else
                        ssc(k, l) = 0
                    End If

                    img.SetPixel(k, l, Color.FromArgb(ssc(k, l), ssc(k, l), ssc(k, l)))
            Next l, k
        Next j

        PictureBox2.Refresh()
    Next i
    mp3 = 0 : nd = 1
    For k = 0 To w
        For l = j To h
            mp3 = mp3 + imageArray(k, l)
            nd = nd + 1
    Next l, k
    mp3 = mp3 / nd
    For k = 0 To w
        For l = j To h
            If imageArray(k, l) >= mp3 Then ssc(k, l) = 255 Else ssc(k, l) = 0
                            img.SetPixel(k, l, Color.FromArgb(ssc(k, l), ssc(k, l), ssc(k, l)))
    Next l, k
    mp3 = 0 : nd = 0
    For k = i To w
        For l = 0 To h
            mp3 = mp3 + imageArray(k, l)
            nd = nd + 1
    Next l, k
    mp3 = mp3 / nd
    For k = i To w
        For l = 0 To h
            If imageArray(k, l) >= mp3 Then ssc(k, l) = 255 Else ssc(k, l) = 0
                            img.SetPixel(k, l, Color.FromArgb(ssc(k, l), ssc(k, l), ssc(k, l)))

    Next l, k
    hpp = 0
    PictureBox2.Image = img

End Sub
```

....... THE code of loading the image is working ,but Idont know if it store the values of the array properly or not ,and it is as following

```
    Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    ofd.Filter = "Bitmap files (*.bmp)|*.bmp"
    If ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        If ofd.FileName <> String.Empty Then
            Me.PictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(ofd.FileName)
        End If
    End If
    Dim img As New Bitmap(ofd.FileName)
    Dim imageArray(img.Width, img.Height) As Integer
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim k As Double
    For i = 0 To img.Width - 1
        For j = 0 To img.Height - 1
            Dim pixel As Color = img.GetPixel(i, j)
            imageArray(i, j) = pixel.ToArgb()
            z(i, j) = imageArray(i, j)
            k = k + imageArray(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It would make things much easier for some to understand if you used proper variable names :(

Comment: Is this method used to convert a color image to grayscale? If so, you can simply apply a [ColorMatrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix.-ctor) to the Bitmap [ImageAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageattributes). It's really fast, also because it doesn't use `.SetPixel()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
Public Shared Function GetArrayFromImage(image As Image) As Byte()
    If image IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim ic As New ImageConverter()
        Dim buffer As Byte() = DirectCast(ic.ConvertTo(image, GetType(Byte())), Byte())
        Return buffer
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Why The ToArgb() method return always -1 value in the following code? Pleas help                      .For i = 0 To img.Width - 1
            For j = 0 To img.Height - 1
                Dim pixel As Color = img.GetPixel(i, j)
                imageArray(i, j) = pixel.ToArgb()

Comment: I changed my function, try it